# Why is this fragment still displayed after orientation change?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a simple app where there user has to fill in some registration information first and login. If the user is already logged in, a different layout will be shown when the `MainActivity` is launched. Pretty standard of most apps these days.

To accommodate this, the layout of my `MainActivity` is this:

```
<RelativeLayout...>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar .../>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I swap in a fragment depending on whether the user is registered or not and I dont seem to understand how the lifecycle of the activity works here.

My `onCreate` looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fragmentContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
    mgr = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // ALWAYS INITIALIZE!
    PrefUtils.init(getApplicationContext());

    if( PrefUtils.readBoolean(KEY_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE,false) ){
        // if registration is complete:
        // TODO: add functionality
    }else{
        // if registration is not complete
        // we need to show the RegisterFragment
        // but first we need to see if we are here
        // because of an orientation change
        // we are avoiding recreating the fragment
        // so that we can show the previously saved state
        Fragment frag = mgr.findFragmentByTag(Fragments.REGISTER_FRAGMENT);
        FragmentTransaction ft = mgr.beginTransaction();
        if( frag != null ){
            // orientation has changed
            // nothing to do
            // fragment was already added previously
            Log.d("FRAG","reuse");
        }else{
            // we are here because the activity has just been created
            // we should create a new fragment
            RegisterFragment regFrag = RegisterFragment.newInstance();
            regFrag.setRetainInstance(true);
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_bottom, R.anim.exit_to_bottom);
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, regFrag, Fragments.REGISTER_FRAGMENT);
            Log.d("FRAG", "new");
        }
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

If orientation change means that the activity is re-created after being destroyed, why is my registration fragment still here with its saved state? Shouldn't the `fragment_container` have been destroyed, requiring me to re-add / re-create the fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regFrag.setRetainInstance(true);`

This tells Android to retain your fragment in the event that the host activity is destroyed due to a configuration change such as rotating the device.  The fragment's `onDestroyView()`, and `onDetach()` methods will be called but the fragment is not destroyed (`onDestroy()` is not called).

When the new host activity is created, the fragment will be reattached (`attach()`) and it's `onCreateView()` method will be called again.

If you WANT your fragment to be destroyed and recreated along with the host activity, don't call `retainInstance(true)` (it's false by default).

I should have also said that the original fragment manager is destroyed along with the host activity, but the fragment is passed off to the new fragment manager and added to the same container that it was in previously.  This is why the fragment is already in the layout when your `onCreate()` method is called.

Comment: Oh okay ! I understand that `setRetainInstance(t)` tells android that *hey, when activity is recreated, re-attach the fragment to its container R.id.fragment_container*. How would this work if, after rotation, the layout changed to a master-detail flow? I hope I am being articulate :)

Comment: You want to make sure that you've got a container with the same ID in both layouts.  The fragment will be added to the container with the same ID that it was in previously.  Also note that retain instance works ONLY in the event that the host activity is destroyed as a result of a configuration change.  If it's destroyed for some other reason (like pressing the back button) then the fragment is destroyed as well.

Comment: Okay, going over the docs for `setRetainInstance()` I found this "*This can only be used with fragments not in the back stack*". Suppose I am stacking fragments one over the other by using `add( )` and calling `addToBackStack(null)` so that every back press would pop the fragments one by one. Would this prevent `setRetainInstance(t)` from working across config change?

Comment: As the documentation says, fragments on the back stack will not be retained.  By why are you setting retain instance to true if you don't want the fragment to be retained?  Why not set it to false or don't set it at all (it's false by default)?

Comment: I do want the state to be retained. I thought that re-creation would require me to re-add. I didn't know Android would automatically re-add the fragment to the new container

Comment: Retain fragment should be used in special cases where there is some part of the fragment's state that it doesn't make sense to persist/restore through the normal mechanism (i.e. `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`).  It is not meant to be a shortcut around having to save and restore state to/from a Bundle.  There are some cases (such as an activity on the back stack being destroyed to reclaim resources) where relying on retaining the instance will not help

Comment: Oh. Special cases like what?

Comment: Mostly for maintaining continuity during a configuration change.  One common example is playing sounds.  You want the sound(s) to keep playing without a skip or restart when the device is rotated.  It's not meant to persist state.